# Boosting a Lithium Coin Cell

Tags: batteries, boost, lithium, coin-cell

I made [a board](http://solderpad.com/vicatcu/ir-duino/) recently and just started checking it out yesterday. I used a typical lithium coin cell and a boost converter ([Microchip MCP1640](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22234B.pdf)). With a battery plugged in I get no voltage out of the boost converter (i.e. 5V to GND measures 0V). Worse yet, I measure very nearly 0V from BATT_PWR to GND with the battery in circuit.

So I removed the battery and fed 3V from a benchtop power supply into the FTDI_PWR net and sure enough was able to measure 5V. The PSU indicated I was drawing about 50mA. I experimented with lowering the voltage, and the booster held 5V, but current draw increased as input voltage decreased (which I believe is expected).

So, is the peculiar battery behavior described above due to the battery current limiting? Is there likely to be some more insidious problem at work here - how might I determine that? If this is the wrong way to boost a coin cell to 5V, what's a better way?

Comment: Please post a schematic here.

Comment: Are you able to measure the bootstrap current needed by the converter at start-up? If it is too high for the coin cell to provide instantaneously, that may be a problem. Also, any reservoir cap at the output will increase this bootstrap current requirement, so I'd play with that to check.

Comment: Re. "*what's a better way?*", the [Texas Instruments BQ25504 Boost Converter](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25504.pdf) will bootstrap from as little as 450 mV and 50 microWatts, and operate down to 80 mV once cold start is complete.

Comment: 50ma is quite a lot for a coin cell. If the startup current is higher than this, the converter may never start up.

Comment: Which coin cell are you using?

Comment: Try lowering the load and see if it starts up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Schottky diodes don't make great blocking diodes for the purpose of power rails. They have often have high reverse leakage currents.
2. Your initial in-rush current is probably high causing the battery voltage to dip below the part's UVLO. To verify this put a scope on your battery and set it to trigger on it dipping more than 100mV below it's nominal value. Make sure you are looking at things at micro-second resolution (like 10 us/div). Post your results here.

Also, if your current requirements are low (<150mA) you can get away w/ a charge-pump.